# CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync() is Very Slow in a UWP App

Tags: c#, performance, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am writing a UWP app (Universal Windows App) in C# for a Windows 10 Mobile phone running anniversary edition of the O/S.  I am trying to use the app to take a photo and then process the photo.  The problem is that the app takes a long time to take a picture.  The first photo takes 5 to 6 seconds, subsequent photos take 3 seconds each.  On the other hand, the built-in Camera app in the same phone only takes 1/2 second or less to take a picture.  Clearly something is wrong with my app.  I narrow it down to one single command that is taking a very long time to finish -- that is CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync().

Please note that both my app and the built-in Camera app save the photo in Picture Library (Windows Phone --> Phone --> Pictures). The only difference is that mine saves photos right in the "Pictures" folder. On the other hand, the built-in Camera app saves photos in "Pictures\Camera Roll" folder.  I doubt this makes any difference.

I thought my app may be saving the photo in the cloud storage or something.  But I still have the same problem when I have unplugged the USB cable from the phone and I have turned OFF WiFi from the phone (the phone doesn't have data plan).  And I have verified Settings --> System --> Storage that photos should be saved in "This Device".

The speed of the phone should not matter because as mentioned above that the built-in Camera app can take photos very fast in the same phone. This means the hardware of the phone is more than capable to take photos very quickly.  Therefore, this is not a hardware problem.

The app has the same problem running under the debugger or outside the debugger.

The app has the same problem when I build it in "Debug" mode or in "Release" mode.

I have prepared a simplified version of my app for your review.  Hopefully you can spot the error that I haven't noticed.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
    ï»¿<Page
    x:Class="Checkout.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Checkout"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="OnLoaded">

   <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
         <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <CaptureElement x:Name="captureElement"  Grid.Row="0" Stretch="Uniform" />
      <Button         x:Name="btnCapture"      Grid.Row="1" Content="Capture Photo" Click="btnCapture_OnClick" />
      <TextBlock      x:Name="lblMsg"          Grid.Row="2" Text="Show message here" />
      <Button         x:Name="btnTerminateApp" Grid.Row="3" Content="Terminate App" Click="btnTerminateApp_OnClick" />

   </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    ï»¿using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;                    // For DeviceInformation, DeviceClass.
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.Capture;                          // For MediaCapture.
using Windows.Media.Devices;                          // For FocusSettings, FocusMode, AutoFocusRange.
using Windows.Media.MediaProperties;                  // For ImageEncodingProperties.
using Windows.Storage;                                // For StorageFile.
using Windows.UI.Popups;                              // For MessageDialog().
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Checkout
   {
   /// <summary>
   /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
   /// </summary>
   public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
      {
      private MediaCapture captureMgr { get; set; }

      public MainPage()
         {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         }

      private void OnLoaded( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
         {
         this.lblMsg.Text = "";

         // Create a new instance of MediaCapture and start the camera in preview mode.
         this.InitCapture();
         }

      private async void btnCapture_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
         {
         // Acknowledge that the user has triggered a button to capture a barcode.
         this.lblMsg.Text = "-------";

         // Capture the photo from the camera to a storage-file.
         ImageEncodingProperties fmtImage = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();
         StorageLibrary libPhoto = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync( KnownLibraryId.Pictures );
         StorageFile storefile =
            await libPhoto.SaveFolder.CreateFileAsync( "BarcodePhoto.jpg",
                                                       CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting );
         await this.captureMgr.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync( fmtImage, storefile );

         // Tell the user that we have taken a picture.
         this.lblMsg.Text = "Picture taken";
         }

      private void btnTerminateApp_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
         {
         this.ReleaseCapture();
         Application.Current.Exit();
         }

      private async void InitCapture()
         // Initialize everything about MediaCapture.
         {
         this.captureMgr = new MediaCapture();
         await this.captureMgr.InitializeAsync();

         // Use the lowest resolution in order to speed up the process.
         this.SetCaptureElementToMinResolution();

         // Start the camera preview.
         captureElement.Source = this.captureMgr;
         await this.captureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();

         // Ask the camera to auto-focus now.
         var focusControl = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl;
         var settings = new FocusSettings { Mode           = FocusMode.Continuous,
                                            AutoFocusRange = AutoFocusRange.FullRange };
         focusControl.Configure( settings );
         await focusControl.FocusAsync();

         #region Error handling
         MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler handler = (sender, e) =>
            {
             System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () =>
               {
               await new MessageDialog( "There was an error capturing the video from camera.", "Error" ).ShowAsync();
               });
            };

         this.captureMgr.Failed += handler;
         #endregion
         }

      private async void SetCaptureElementToMinResolution()
         // Set the CaptureElement to the minimum resolution that the device
         // can handle. We need to set it to lowest resolution in other to
         // speed up the process.
         {
         VideoEncodingProperties resolutionMin = null; 
         int nMinResolutionSoFar = -1;
         var lisResolution = this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties( MediaStreamType.Photo );

         for( var i = 0; i< lisResolution.Count; i++ )
            {
            VideoEncodingProperties resCur = (VideoEncodingProperties)lisResolution[ i ];
            int nCurResolution = (int)( resCur.Width * resCur.Height );
            if (nMinResolutionSoFar == -1)
               {
               nMinResolutionSoFar = nCurResolution;
               resolutionMin       = resCur;
               }
            else if ( nMinResolutionSoFar > nCurResolution )
               {
               nMinResolutionSoFar = nCurResolution;
               resolutionMin       = resCur;
               }
            }

         await this.captureMgr.VideoDeviceController.SetMediaStreamPropertiesAsync( MediaStreamType.Photo, resolutionMin );
         }

      private async void ReleaseCapture()
         // Release the resources used for capturing photo.
         {
         try
            {
            captureElement.Source = null;
            await this.captureMgr.StopPreviewAsync();
            this.captureMgr.Dispose();
            }
         catch( Exception ex )
            {
            String sErrMsg = String.Concat( "Fail to release resources related to the ",
                                            "use of the camera. The error message is: ",
                                            ex.Message );
            await new MessageDialog( sErrMsg, "Error" ).ShowAsync();
            }
         }


      }
   }
```

If you want to try this app in your computer, please create a new project, and enable the following capabilities in the project: Internet (default), Microphone, and Webcam.  And then copy the code from those two files shown above.

Please try it and let me know how it goes in your computer/phone.

My phone is Microsoft Lumia 550, Windows 10 Mobile, 1GB RAM, version 1607, OS build: 10.0.14393.693.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Jay Chan

Comment: I have reset the phone.  But the problem is still there.  However, when I try the same program in a different phone, I find that the performance is acceptable (1 to 2 seconds delay instead of 5 to 6 seconds).  The one that I am having a problem with is Lumia 550, and the one that has acceptable performance is Lumia 635.

Comment: I have also tried the same program in the third Windows phone, and that one doesn't have the problem either (that is a Lumia 640 LTE).  Seem like only one phone has this problem. The one that has problem has Snapdragon 210 with Adreno 304.  The two that don't have problem have Snapdragon 400 with Adreno 305.